# Receiving double-click event

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mouseevent, nsevent

I've been searching the Apple docs and the only function I could find pertaining to a double click just returned the acceptable time between clicks for it to be considered a double click.

Can someone please show me an example of a double click event?

Comment: @duskwuff OSX (see tags)

Comment: @duskwuff: Also, iOS doesn't have clicks.

Comment: Right, I was wondering if you were looking for a (probably non-existent?) "double tap" event on iOS.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Override the `NSResponder` method `-mouseUp:` and check the supplied event's `clickCount`. If `clickCount == 2`, then you're looking at a double-click. If it's 1, then a single click. 0, then they waited long enough between mouse down and mouse up that the system decided it's not a click, just distinct down then up events.

```
- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)event
{
    NSInteger clickCount = [event clickCount];
    if (2 == clickCount) [self handleDoubleClickEvent:event];
}
```

This assumes the object handling the click is part of the responder chain. If not, you'll have to get your events another way, like subclassing `NSApplication` or `NSWindow` and overriding `-sendEvent:` to intercept the appropriate event before it gets passed along any further.

Comment: It should be emphasized that “NSResponder” in this answer refers to the class in Cocoa (which NSView, NSWindow, and NSApplication inherit from), not the other answerer who named himself after it.

Answer (score 4):

See NSEvent's `-clickCount` method.

Answer (score 2):

Note also that some `NSControl` has `setDoubleAction:` so that the selector registered via `setDoubleAction:` is sent to the target. See  the official documentations of

- [`NSTableView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000118-SW31) ,
- [`NSStatusItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000248-BAJIEAJJ) ,
- [`NSPathControl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSPathControl_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004618-CH3-SW8) ,
- [`NSBrowser`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBrowser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000078-BAJCFDBC) ,
- [`NSMatrix`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMatrix_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000106-setDoubleAction_) .

Comment: The event (NSEvent object) is not passed to the target; an action message is sent to the target, but, as usual for an action message, the single argument is the control (table view or whatever) sending the message. I'm sure you didn't mean the NSEvent object, but I wanted to make sure that's clear.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant; I'll rephrase it. Thanks.

Comment: In my case I had to set a target for an NSTableView when running on OS prior to 10.10, but 10.10 worked OK without the target being set (self in my case)